# Count the number of bits that are "on" in a byte

Tags: c#, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Count the number of set bits in an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357932/count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-an-integer)
>   [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

That's an exam question and that is all I have - "Count the number of bits that are "on" in a byte" "On" means 1, I assume. Do I need to create a BitArray, randomly populate it and then iterate through it or is there a different way?

Comment: check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

Comment: Also related - [Counting bits set in a .Net BitArray Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5063178/465053)

Answer (score 8):

Using BitArray might be efficient but you could also do

```
byte b = ... ;

int count = Convert.ToString(b,2).ToCharArray().Count(c => c=='1');
```

Comment: I think that is called a lambda expression, right? BtW, sorry I can not upvote, I am not registered yet.

Comment: yes `c => c == '1'` is a lambda expression predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a interview question?

For a byte the fastest way would be to pre-compute an array such that a[i] = number of bits in i - the memory overhead is negligible.

Comment: http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/

Comment: Unless it's for an embedded system. Then, doing it by the nibble is a better tradeoff.